# Comparing data.table::setorder against base::sort

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to sort rows of `data.table` (R-3.3.1 Win x64 & data.table_1.9.6) and found that the `setorder` is different from the `base::sort`. Am I using setorder correctly?

```
dt <- data.table(A=c("AA","AB","Ab"))
setorder(dt, A)
identical(dt[,A], sort(dt[["A"]]))
#[1] FALSE

df <- data.frame(A=c("AA","AB","Ab"))
identical(df[order(df$A),"A"], sort(df[["A"]]))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reproduce this with `sort` if we set the method to "radix" which was adopted in base R from data.table's sorting:

```
sort(dt[["A"]])
#[1] "AA" "Ab" "AB"
sort(dt[["A"]], method = "radix")
#[1] "AA" "AB" "Ab"
```

In `help("sort")` we find:

> Except for method
>   "radix", the sort order for character vectors will depend on the
>   collating sequence of the locale in use: see Comparison.
>   ...
>
> However, there are some caveats with the radix sort: If x is a character vector, all elements must share the same encoding.
>   Only UTF-8 (including ASCII) and Latin-1 encodings are supported.
>   Collation always follows the "C" locale.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "C")
sort(dt[["A"]])
#[1] "AA" "AB" "Ab"
```